# tDBLookupComboBox displays (MEMO)

Tags: delphi

I have a `tDBLookupComboBox`.  All the text appears as "`(MEMO)`".  I've checked the `LookupSource` dataset and the `LookupField` for all records contains the expected text.  What could be wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `LookupField` is of type `varchar(max)`.  To solve the problem I changed the `LookupSource` query to cast it to `varchar(250)`.

I had this problem and could not find an answer online.  I'm posting the question and answer so future visitors will be able to find the solution sooner.

Answer (score 1):

I use ZeosDbo and Lazarus. TDBLookupComboBox shows (Memo). I did some research and found GetText method.
I wrote a method which is:

```
procedure GetText(Sender: TField; var aText: string;
  DisplayText: boolean);
begin
  if (Sender.DataType = ftMemo) then
  begin
    aText := Sender.AsString;
    DisplayText := True;
  end;
end;
```

and gave it method address:

```
ZQuery.FieldByName('FieldName').OnGetText := @GetText;
```